# deny use of response.write

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I made a base class. It inherits from

> System.Web.Ui.Page

.
In this class I display several components with

> response.write

in the web.config i set the base class automatic to this base class

How can I keep using the response.write in my base classes but prevent an programmer that he uses response.write because i want to keep complete control over what gets into display.

I can not find how to overrides the write function and ignore it if it is not coming from a base class.

M.